# Should I use a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uitextview

Everybody, I'd like to know if in iOS there's a way to edit just some words, not all by keyboard.
Do you think it would be good to use a `NSMutableDictionary` of `NSStrings` with keys that indicate whether they're editable or not, display them onto a `UILabel`? Then, when I press a key (for example, backspace) I update the label and delete the last character if and only if it is editable.
Do you have better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel` has read-only text. I think you need an `UITextField`, you can manage the text editing using it's delegate (`UITextFieldDelegate`). You can use a dictionary, but I think that a `NSCharacterSet` containing all the editable characters fits better.

It will be something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString* string= [textField.text substringWithRange: range];
    return [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: self.nonEditableCharacterSet].location == NSNotFound;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I create a custom cursor for the 'UITextField'?

Comment: What do you mean by a "custom cursor"? You mean that you want to subclass UITextField?

Comment: I would like to have a cursor like the one in the Terminal app: green and thick. In iOS 7 can I change the cursor's color?

Comment: For this I think you would better use a UIScrollView.

Comment: Could you explain it, please?

Comment: A scroll view manages a view that is scrolled by the user interaction with a scroller, is this what you need?

Comment: So, you mean a textview, since i have to display text.

Comment: Yes, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, you did. So, how could I change the caret color?

Comment: You can just make it be black or white (UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack, UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite), if you need another colour I suggest to use this class: https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

Answer (score 1):

UITextField gives you this capability.  Set the viewController as the delegate of the textField (either in storyboard by control clicking to the left most icon and selecting "delegate" or with the line `self.textField.delegate = self`.  Make sure you declare the viewController is a UITextField delegate in the `@interface`.

From there you can implement `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`
 from [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).  Check for the characters in the range, and see if they are ones you want to be allowed to be edited.  If not, `return NO` otherwise `return YES`.

You cannot edit UILabels, so you should use UITextField for this sort of behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I create a custom cursor for the 'UITextField'?